# Event propagation and ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, event-propagation

I have the following code:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <a href="someurl"> ... </a>
</div>
```

HTML inside the div comes from the external source and I don't know it's structure and can't control it.

I need to post some data when this link has been clicked. So I added an onclick event handler on the div element, hoping event will propagate, and posted data with jQuery ajax function.

This worked fine in all browsers but Safari - it doesn't return any errors, calls the callback function but doesn't reach the server for some reason. I write to database every time I get a request. Tried to manually load the post url in browser - works fine and record in db is created. Also tried FF and Chrome - works as expected.

When put an alert into callback function it's being called but in Safari data = null.

```
$('#parentDiv').delegate( 'a', 'click', function()
{
    $.post('posturl', 
        { param1: 'test'}, 
        function(data)
        { 
            alert('data = '+data);
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

Is it correct to expect AJAX working in this situation at all? And is there a better solution to this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: are you stopping the click event so the browser doesn't try to follow the someurl link?

Comment: What does "doesn't reach the server mean"? Describe _precisely_ what you see, and the metrics with which you measure it.

Comment: No, I don't stop it because I do want it to follow the link and to submit data at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you need to combine `delegate` with the asynchronous AJAX.  Note that this is almost never a good thing -- the only real exception is when you want to do an AJAX request immediately before leaving a page.

Your code might look something like this:

```
$('#parentDiv').delegate( 'a', 'click', function()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'posturl',
      { param1: 'test'}, 
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false
    });
});
```

This waits for the POST request to finish before continuing to follow the link.  Note that this is superior to using `location = url` in a success callback as this solution allows normal browser action like middle-clicking to be followed as normal.

Comment: Going async seems quite sensible, but doesn't work: http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/dasha_salo/index2.php Also, I don't understand how the code which sets `window.location` is problematic...works fine for me and isn't breaking any click functionality.

Comment: @JAAulde It works when I set `async: false`. Sorry for the idiotic error... Middle clicking won't work in your example -- the link will be opened in the current window not in a new one.

Comment: Ah, duh, async false--LOL. Yeah, that is definitely better as it involves less code, etc. +1

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at jQuery's `.delegate()` method. It tells an element to listen for certain event bubbling up from a certain element and to execute behavior when it is observed. You also want to prevent the default action of the link, and send the browser to the link when the ajax operation is complete.

**Docs:** http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

**Sample code:**

```
$( '#parentDiv' ).delegate( 'a', 'click', function( e )
{
    var url = this.href;

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(
        'posturl', 
        {
            param1: 'test'
        },
        function(data)
        {
            alert('data = ' + data);
            window.location = url;
        },
        'json'
    );
} );
```

This:

1. delegates the event
2. prevents default
3. awaits ajax response
4. sends browser to link

**Demo:** http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/dasha_salo/

Comment: I just do getElementById('parentDiv').onlick = function(){...}. Is there any difference?

Comment: How's that working out for you?  LOL ;)  Listen, you already have jQ on the page and in use. It's job is to level the playing field for you between various browsers. One difference here is the checking of the event source is done for you to ensure that you're executing proper behavior for proper interaction.

Comment: Problem is I don't know what elements will be inside the div. If I knew I would add a handler directly at <a> element.

Comment: `.delegate()` can be called before the content lands and will work even if you modify the content. You say you don't know what will be in the DIV, but you're sure it will be a link--you said you need to know "when this link is clicked." Delegate for the selector 'a' and you should be able to catch it. It could be, however, that Safari bubbles so fast, notices you never prevented default, and abandons the script as it heads for the new page. I'm not sure about all that, though.

Comment: Just tried - doesn't make any difference unfortunately :( thank you

Comment: Looking at the code in your edited post. I use `.delegate()` in many places, so I'll see what I can figure out.

Comment: Just tried adding preventDefault and it started working. Doesn't solve the issue though. Thank you!